# Adding a separate index.html as homepage and routing shinyapp to some other page

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have made a shiny app in R and hosted it over the web using shiny-server. Let's say my app is hosted at [www.test.in](http://www.test.in) (just for instance). Now I want to add a simple static HTML page which will contain the link of the app so when the user will visit the URL [www.test.in](http://www.test.in), he will see the HTML page and  [www.test.in/app](http://www.test.in/app) will contain the shiny app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add following `index.html` file in `/srv/shiny-server`:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=//www.test.in:port/app/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Redirecting to <a href="//www.test.in:port/app/">app</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

where `port` should be set to the correct value, for example 3838.
Shiny Server will open this index and redirect to the app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it didn't work. /srv/shiny-server takes app.R as it's index page and not the index.html, so I didn't found any changes.

Comment: usually apps are in a subdirectory of  `/srv/shiny-server` corresponding to the app name. Just put the index at the root of `/srv/shiny-server` .